# Using bluebird promise.all twice

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use the following code which works OK! my question is if there is better way to write it or is it OK? I use the promise all twice but want to verify that I use this promise lib correctly

```
var start = function () {
    return Promise.all([
        chi.getCommand(val1,val2),
        chi.findAndUpdateCustomer()
    ]).then(function (args) {
        return Promise.all([chss.exe(runnableDoc, args[0], args[1]),
            Promise.delay(10).then(function (val) {
                val ? console.log(val) : null;
                return app.getStatus(12)
            })
        ])
    })
}();
```

Comment: Your question is a better fit for the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thoughts:

- I would prefer to use `.spread()` instead of `.then()` in sequence to `Promise.all()` here, it makes using proper variable names easier.
- I am not sure what the enclosing IIFE is supposed to achieve, let's get rid of it.
- The second `Promise.all()` seems superfluous to me in this particular situation.

So my suggestion would be this:

```
var start = Promise.all([
    chi.getCommand(val1, val2),
    chi.findAndUpdateCustomer()
]).spread(function (command, customer) {
    return chss.exe(runnableDoc, command, customer).delay(10).then(function (val) {
        if (val) console.log(val);
        return app.getStatus(12);
    });
});
```

Notes

- Try to use a better name than `start`, i.e. sth. that represents the *result* of the operation, not the irrelevant fact that you have started the operation.
- What is the 10ms delay supposed to do? I don't see a need for that.
- In the above sample `val` will refer to the result of the `chss.exe()` call. In your setup however, `val` would always be `undefined`; I expect that wasn't the intention.
- The end result of a successful promise chain will always be `app.getStatus(12)`. But in case of an error the result is not clear. For the sake of symmetry you should add a `.catch()` that returns a different app status.

Comment: Thanks 1+, few short questions :) why should I skip the IIFE I need it ? 2. why val will always be null? 3. if I should use catch where you suggest to put in case i got an error from one of the promise?

Comment: 1) As I said, I did not see what benefit the IIFE would bring. In this short example exactly none, since there are no variables you create a closure for. `var foo = (function () { return "foo" })();` is the same as `var foo = "foo";`, that's how I see the code here. 2) `undefined`, not `null`. It's because `Promise.delay(10)` never produces any value. 3) It was only a note/suggestion. If you want to do your error handling somewhere else, it's completely up to you.